# jQuery fadeIn Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function change(){
    setInterval(function() {
    var textSpan = $('#aboutUsText');
    if (textSpan.attr("MyState")=="2"){
        textSpan.text('Info 1');
        textSpan.fadeIn("slow");
        textSpan.attr("MyState", "1");
    }else if (textSpan.attr("MyState")=="3"){
        textSpan.text('Info 2');
        textSpan.attr("MyState", "2");
    }else{
        textSpan.text('Info 3');
        textSpan.attr("MyState", "3");
    }
    }, 3000);
}
window.onload = function start() {
    change();
}
```

The code works fine, But i am trying to make the text fade in before the Info 1 section, I cannot see why this is not working? I am using Jquery, Many thanks :3

Comment: How is it not working? What is happening and what you do you want to happen(expected and actual behavior)?

Comment: Full code required....

Comment: Also replicating this in jsfiddle.net will help people to understand your problem better.

Comment: The code is scrolling, But the fade on line 6 is not making the element change, Here is the relevent html: http://pastebin.com/RivDzHxL

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NpGXC/ The problem is it does not seem to scroll on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things going on with your code that prevented the text from fading in.

- `#aboutUsText` had no `opacity` set via CSS, so it was already fully opaque and there was nothing for `fadeIn` to do.
- `fadeIn` usually expects your element to have `display: none;` set; since you had a block-level paragraph, `fadeIn` had nothing to do here, too.
- The attribute you were attempting to check was not in either of the examples, so your check would always fail.

[Here's a working fiddle that is fading that text in.](http://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/NpGXC/1/) Note that I changed a few things:

- I used `data-` attributes to store your state. These are the preferred way of storing arbitrary data on a given element as per the HTML spec.
- I added `opacity` to `#aboutUsText` so it had somewhere to fade into.
- I used `fadeTo` instead of `fadeIn`, since your element is block-level and displayed.

I also used a switch statement instead of if/else since I find that a bit more readable, but that is a matter of personal preference.

Happy fading!

Answer (score 0):

Your element is already showing. So there is not any option to reshow it. At first you need to   hide the `<p>` then apply `fadeIn()`. Try this updated example :

```
    function change(){
        setInterval(function() {
        var textSpan = $('#aboutUsText');
        if (textSpan.attr("MyState")=="2"){
            //I have added the line below
            textSpan.prop('hidden',true);
            textSpan.fadeIn("slow");
            textSpan.text('Text 1');
            textSpan.attr("MyState", "1");
        }else if (textSpan.attr("MyState")=="3"){
            textSpan.text('Text 2');
            textSpan.attr("MyState", "2");
        }else{
            textSpan.text('Text3');
            textSpan.attr("MyState", "3");
        }
        }, 3000);
    }
    change();
```

You can also find the updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NpGXC/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your element is already showing. So there is not any option to reshow it. At first you need to hide the

using css or hidden propery of `<p>` then apply `fadeIn()`.
I have used `hidden` property technique for the sake of simplicity.

You can also improve your code by decoupling the decision making info from the function itself by injecting a json object and using the power of dictionary. Here is a working example with the suggested improvements :

```
function change(StateTransitions){
    setInterval(function() {
        var textSpan = $('#aboutUsText');
        var state = textSpan.data('state');
        textSpan.text(StateTransitions[state]["text"]);
        textSpan.data("state",StateTransitions[state]["state"]);
        if(StateTransitions[state]["fadeIn"]){
            textSpan.prop("hidden", true);
            textSpan.fadeIn("slow");
        }            
    }, 3000);
}
change({
    "2":{
        "state": "1",
        "text" : "Text 1",
        "fadeIn" : true
    },
    "3":{
        "state": "2",
        "text" : "Text 2"
    },
    "1":{
        "state": "3",
        "text" : "Text 3"
    },

});
```

You can find the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NpGXC/3/)